# TeamViewer on 22.04 remote access

Tags: remote-desktop, 22.04, teamviewer

I am trying to use TeamViewer to remote into my Ubuntu-based server, so that I could manage it when I am away. The problem is, every time I try to remote into the server, I get this message displayed:

[image]

The problem with this is that I have to be present next to the server to be able to get rid of it and start the TeamViewer session. Is there a way to get rid of it for good, so that I could remote into the server without being next to it? Thanks in advance.
I assume this is some stupid privacy or security thing, but I didn't find anything about it online.

Comment: Have you tried using the host version of Teamviewer? Also, why are you using team viewer to access your server remotely and not any other [tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh&oq=ssh&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.1515j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Ubuntu servers do not have any GUI. TeamViewer is not the right tool for remote access to command line interface. Use `ssh` instead. Update your question if you are using the Desktop version of Ubuntu.

Comment: If you want a remote desktop, use remmina with vnc or the like. If you don't have a desktop, use ssh.

Comment: I am using TeamViewer because I already have it on all my other devices, so I don't want to switch. I don't know what you mean by "Host Version".

Answer (score 11):

So the problem with a default install of Ubuntu is the Wayland GNOME requires a user at the desktop to accept the TeamViewer connection. Of course that doesn't work for Unmanned Kiosks or IOT machines.

To change to the `X11 GNOME`, you need to make a simple change to config file. Navigate to `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

In that config file look for this line:

```
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false
```

All you have to do is delete the `#` to uncomment the `WaylandEnable=false`. Then restart the computer and connect with TeamViewer.

---

That sounds simple, but if you have just installed the default Ubuntu, you don't have permission to make changes to this file.

If you are familiar with a terminal file editor, such as vim, simply open this file using the editor with `sudo`:

```
sudo vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Otherwise, first you must give yourself sudo permission for this folder. To give yourself permission, open the terminal and type this:

`sudo chmod a+rwx /etc/gdm3`

When you run that line it will ask for your password. Once complete, you should be able to save the change to the `custom.conf` file mentioned above.

Comment: Worked for me. For simplicity, just use `sudo vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.

Answer (score 5):

Ok so I found out that Ubuntu's windowing sistem, Wayland, and TeamViewer don't like each other. To use TeamViewer on Ubuntu 22.04, you need to use X11. Now everything is working fine.