# How to grant permanent remote desktop access to TeamViewer

Tags: permissions, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I use TeamViewer to remote access my computer which is running Ubuntu 22.04. I set up easy access and assigned the computer to my account and granted full access, but when i am trying to connect to the computer, a "Portal" windows pops up where I have to allow TeamViewer Remote control the computer:

[image]

How can I let it automatically allow sharing, without being there and manually toggle it with the mouse? I have enabled Remote Desktop in the settings, but I can't find any settings to grant TeamViewer permanently permission. How can I solve this, do I have to give TeamViewer administration rights or change something in the privacy? Please help, i am very desperated about this! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TeamViewer on 22.04 remote access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407825/teamviewer-on-22-04-remote-access)