# Teamviewer not running in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, wayland, teamviewer

I have been searching for a solution but cannot find anyone. I have used Teamviewer in some earlier versions of Ubuntu, but after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, I am not able to run Teamviewer anymore, and cannot find any online help.

The only info which I have found is that Ubuntu's windowing system manager Wayland and Teamviewer don't like each other.

Is there any way I could get over it without me needing to logout to change the windowing system?

The following are useful links about my question:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1408191/64910
- https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/125357/teamviewer-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04-since-i-installed-it-4-months-ago-when-is-the-fix-coming

Comment: The question you linked has the necessary answers already, nothing has changed afaik.

Comment: Change the windowing system before you login.